# Match string in brackets if there is more than one variable name

Tags: regex, sas

I'm struggling to find the correct regex pattern to match a string in brackets if more than one variable name is found within the brackets.

For example in this string:

RESP_VAR1 IN (408, 409) OR (RESP_VAR1 = 231 AND (RESP_DATE >= 20220101 AND RESP_DATE <20220301) ) OR (RESP_VAR1 = 232 AND RESP_VAR1 <= 240) OR (RESP_VAR3 = 1 AND RESP_VAR5 IN ('B', 'G'))

I want to match :

- (RESP_VAR1 = 231 AND (RESP_DATE >= 20220101 AND RESP_DATE <20220301) )
- (RESP_VAR3 = 1 AND RESP_VAR5 IN ('B', 'G'))

and not match:

- RESP_VAR1 IN (408, 409) *# because variable is not within brackets.*
- (RESP_VAR1 = 232 AND RESP_VAR1 <= 240) *# because same variable name is within brackets*

So far, I have built this pattern, but I can't find what I am doing wrong:

/((.*?([A-Z]{1,5}_\w{3,6})(?=.*?\2.*?).*?))/

[See pattern test on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/zyVwN8/3)

Comment: You're using `RESP_DATE` twice in the instance you want to have match: by your own rules, wouldn't that need to be excluded?

Comment: Also, you'd save potential responders some time if you posted what your pattern is returning, and why you don't like what it returns. It's hard to diagnose things when all you know is "this doesn't return what I want".

Comment: Also: are the variables going to all begin with "RESP", or can they potentially be any string?

Comment: @AnnL. Thank you for your questions. 1. RESP_DATE is used twice but is also within brackets with RESP_VAR1 so it is still a valid string to capture. 2. I have included the link to Regex101.com where my pattern is saved with the test strings. 3. the variables names have some variation: 2 to 5 letters, underscore and, a combination of letters and digits from 3 up to 6 characters of length  \b[A-Z]{1,5}_\w{3,6}\b.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the .*? after the opening parentheses.

```
data test;
  string =
      "RESP_VAR1 IN (408, 409)"
    ||" OR (RESP_VAR1 = 231 AND (RESP_DATE >= 20220101 AND RESP_DATE <20220301) )"
    ||" OR (RESP_VAR1 = 232 AND RESP_VAR1 <= 240)"
    ||" OR (RESP_VAR3 = 1 AND RESP_VAR5 IN ('B', 'G'))"
  ;
  id=prxparse('/(\(([A-Z]{1,5}_[A-Z]{3,6})(?=.*?\2.*?).*?\))/');
  start=1;
  stop=length(string);
  do i=1 by 1 until(position=0);
    call prxnext(id, start, stop, string, position, length);
    substring=substrn(string,position,length);
    put (i position length substring) (=);
    start=position+length+1;
  end;
run;
```

Results:

```
i=1 position=28 length=68 substring=(RESP_VAR1 = 231 AND (RESP_DATE >= 20220101 AND RESP_DATE <20220301)
i=2 position=102 length=38 substring=(RESP_VAR1 = 232 AND RESP_VAR1 <= 240)
i=3 position=144 length=42 substring=(RESP_VAR3 = 1 AND RESP_VAR5 IN ('B', 'G')
i=4 position=0 length=0 substring=
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Unfortunately this does not resolve the issue,  (RESP_VAR1 = 232 AND RESP_VAR1 <= 240) should not be matched but still is in your answer. I’m looking at capturing everything within brackets if there is a least 2 different variables names. Also, I corrected the pattern to capture the variable names [A-Z]{1,5}_\w{3,6}, it was wrong my initial post. Thanks

Comment: Trying to exclude cases where the same name appears twice is probably not something you would want to do in the same regex.  Or at least I wouldn't.